# Error in for loop when looping through a specific column in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm a beginner in R programming. I was doing an exercise for an online course and I came up with a question (which does not concern the exercise itself). I have the following DF:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   915 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ sal: int  22000000 15714286 13650000 13571429 13350000 13050000 13000000 12600000 12500000 12500000 ...
 $ AB : int  632 36 574 503 80 529 NA 614 577 364 ...
 $ OBP: num  0.399 0.154 0.408 0.384 0.143 ...
```

I had to make a function which returned me the first three numbers of the column `$sal` for which the sum was 15 million. Here's what I did:

```
> for(i in DF){
+     x <- 1
+     y <- 3
+     while(sum(i[x:y]) > 15*10^6){
+         x <- x + 1
+         y <- y + 1
+         if(sum(i[x:y]) <= 15*10^6){
+             print(c(x:y))
+         }
+     }
+ }
[1] 138 139 140
```

This works, but of course, the for will run through the entire DF. If I wanted it to run only through a specific column, I'd set `for(i in DF$column)`. However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in while (sum(i[x:y]) > 15 * 10^6) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is my question: why is this happening? Hope my question was clear.

Comment: I think the problem is in i[x:y]. i has length 1. Besides, that problem would be one line in R. No need for the loop.

Comment: Just to point it out, have a look how the following works: `df <- data.frame(sal = 1:10); 
which(cumsum(df$sal) > 15)[1:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have missing values in you data (see your column `AB`).

Try replacing `sum(...)` by `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`.

By the way, what you could do instead of looping is something like:

```
test <- round(runif(100) * 1e7)
test[1] <- NA
test2 <- RcppRoll::roll_sum(test, n = 3, na.rm = TRUE)
sapply(which(test2 > 15e6), function(x) x + 0:2) 
# outer(0:2, which(test2 > 15e6), '+') may be faster
```